# How to add custom Css in nextjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I was trying to add these [Template](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_coming_soon&stacked=h) into one of my Components, this component also gets other values dynamically.
But I'm getting this error instead

`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`

I also tried [next-images](https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images) in `next.config.js` but still gives me the same error.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "next": "^9.3.6",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.12.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1"
  }
}
```

Update:

My next.config.js

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({

    publicRuntimeConfig : {
        APP_NAME : '  ',
        API_DEVELOPMENT : '',
        API_PRODUCTION : '',
        PRODUCTION:false

    }
})
```

Comment: what does your next.config.js looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this in your next.config.js:**

`// next.config.js`

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({

  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false

  }
})
```